# how to stacking image on top of another

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

im a beginner at css,i have several image and i attempting to stack image on top of another.
im using framework bootstrap 4.1

**EXAMPLE**

Expected result what i want:

[image]

**Question**

I need the second image(the women) is on the bottom of div.

here my work

```
.bg-light{
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
.lia-main{
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
.lia-char{
    width:37%;
    height:auto;
    right: 0;
    vertical-align : bottom;
}
```

See the jsfiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/iqballord/g1bp65v3/)

Comment: can you check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Aravi/j2qLdt75 and let me know this is what you needed

Comment: when i try in my browser the background not 100% width and height.and the navbar section is different component do not stack with the navbar

Comment: can you add you navbar component also in the code..i mean something is missing in navbar @mohamad igbal - here is a n updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Aravi/j2qLdt75

Comment: i already updated my js fiddle an new image what i expected.please check @AravindS

Comment: Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Aravi/82om610w/

Answer (score 0):

The background and the woman are in a separate `div` than the two logos, because of this reason they are not getting stacked on top of each other as you desire.

Here is your modified HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-light">       

<img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/2nb53ba.jpg" class='img-fluid position-absolute lia-main'> 

<div class="front">
    <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            logo
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-brand pull-right" href="#">
            logo
          </a>
  </div> 

        <div class="woman">
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/jW521y/lia2.png" class='float-right img-fluid lia-char pull-right' >  
        </div>  

</div>
```

The woman is placed in a div since it is supposed to be "above" the rest of the elements.

**UPDATE: Here is a modified fiddle link as per the comments above, also the html code above has changes.**

Here is your modified [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/106003/)